# Flask - log of requests

Tags: unix, flask, cmd, command-line, raspbian

When I'm executing the "flask run" command in cmd, flask starts to show a log of HTTP requests and errors/warnings.
How can I reshow this log-printing state in the cmd after I close the cmd and open it again?

I'm using raspberry pi so my question referred to the UNIX cmd in the raspbien OS.

Comment: Do you want to see the logs of earlier requests when you restart your Flask webserver? That's not possible. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to open again the mode where I can see the requests in real time in the cmd.

Comment: Do `flask run` again? If that's not working then please include more info in the question.

Comment: I’m running the flask via automatic script when my raspberry pi boots up so the flask api running in the background. I‘m trying to open the log of requests in the cmd

Comment: Please add information to the question about your setup. We can't help you know, there's not enough information.

Comment: this is the automatic code that runs when the OS boots up:
cd /home/pi/Desktop
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
sudo -E flask run --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80

By default, flask returns the log of the API requests to the cmd where you run this script.
My question is:
Because I didn't  run the flask from the cmd (and it runs automatic when the OS boots up) how can I enter this mode on the cmd that I can see the api requests logs?
when running "flask run" again it just creates a new flask process of the same app.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the new information. Don't use comments for this.